# Can't see 35% gas optimization on protocol 009

Tags: protocol, gas

I looked around and could not see any example of known smart contract (FA1.2, FA2, etc) that is now using less gas then before Florence protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Florence gas optimizations are only about the Michelson interpreter.

During a call to a smart contract, gas is charged for the following things:

1. checking the signature of the operation
2. account management (debiting the caller and crediting the smart contract)
3. fetching the script and the storage of the contract from disk
4. conversion from a byte sequence to an internal representation of the protocol
5. actual execution
6. conversion of the updated storage from the internal representation to a byte sequence
7. saving of the updated storage on disk

Florence gas optimizations are about point number 5. For this step some numbers are given in the following blog post: https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/sound-and-fast-gas-monitoring-with-saturation-arithmetic.html

```
┌──────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ Contract │ Edo    │ Florence │
├──────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ Dexter   │ 44,867 │  28,813  │
│ FA1.2    │  9,718 │   6,238  │
│ Manager  │  3,764 │   2,301  │
└──────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

So the gas reduction for the execution of these three specific scripts are respectively 35.8%, 35.8%, and 38.8%.

Comment: Are, for example, these two Dexter tzBTC/XTZ "tokenToXtz" operations comparable?

Edo https://tzkt.io/onmLRHgCktDndYmEi8T1yA2Wk1Co6gaHbzobr6yNqHr2hY28tp6

Florence https://tzkt.io/opELLfxWeJSfaFr6eNNpXBgeftWAxL5qLxDUNdtv727rBrpfVkU